# Getting import/export eror in reactjs/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
const removeCart = (productId) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM, payload=productId})
}

export default removeCart

export { addToCart }
```

This is being exported as an action for a reducer.
And i am importing that as

```
import removeCart, { addToCart } from '../actions/cartActions';
```

But i get this error "Attempted import error: '../actions/cartActions' does not contain a default export (imported as 'removeCart')."

The route is correct since i am already using another action from the same file.

Comment: Nevermind,fixed it.

Comment: how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put braces around the named export.

Just:

```js
export addToCart
export default removeCart
```